# android scroll view nesting

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to make a layout that has this structure:

```
main_linear 
    scroll_days
        days_linear
            scroll_day
                day
                    hour
                        part
                            text1
                            text2
                        text3
                        text4
```

But I always end up with one scroll for all days. I want every day to have its own vertical scroll, show only 1 day on screen, slide left/right to change days and slide up/down to show hours.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't have a ScrollView inside an other ScrollView.

Comment: Why not, how else am I supposed to create a layout, that can slide up/down and left/right?

Comment: Actually vertical scroll views can be added inside a horizontal scroll view. As long as the scroll views are perpendicular to each other, you will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a custom ListView to achieve that.

You can have a look at https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView which is a listview that handles groups.